# Django: passing urlib2 response to view and https

Tags: django, https, payment-processing

I have to implement a few payment providers like Paypal. Most of these services provide a form with some hidden fields that you then post to their website. I would like to post to one view and let urllib2 post the actually data to the payment provider.

```
def pay_for_stuff(request, provider, amount, order_id):

    if provider == 'some_payment_provider':

        url = 'https://www.some_payment_provider.com'

        values = {
            #post values
        }

        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

This returns a form where a user can fill in their credit card information which posts to a https://... url of the payment service.

The reason I am doing this is because I have to implement a few payment providers and this way I can use one form that posts to a one view.

Is this secure and are there any problems I might have doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

No, of course it's not secure. You are specifically trying to break the security. Luckily, you can't actually do this, so it doesn't matter.

You need to redirect the user to the payment gateway, where they can enter their details.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I tried it in a sandbox and it did seem to work. Maybe I wasn't clear. I am not trying to post the credit card details myself. I am talking about posting to a payment website to get the form that will do the actually processing. On IRC they said if you post to an https url the data you post will actually be secure. For Paypal this will return the login screen I think but for an other service I use you land on a page where you can fill in your credit card details right away because they don't use user accounts.